# Get files in directory with @ionic-native/file

Tags: file, ionic-framework, native

I write files with this code:

```
this.file.writeFile(`${this.file.externalRootDirectory}/app_name/.tmp`, `${this.countPictures}.jpg`, blob, options)
      .then(res => {
        this.countPictures++;
        this.file.resolveLocalFilesystemUrl(res.fullPath).then((data) => {
          this.alertService.show(JSON.stringify(data), 'long', 'bottom')

        })
        this.events.publish('update:badges', 'picture', res.nativeURL);

      }, err => {
        this.alertService.show(`${JSON.stringify(err)}`, 'long', 'bottom')
      });
```

And now, I would like to get this files and  how many are there. I tried to do with: this.file.resolveDirectoryUrl but I dont know how it works.

Thanks